# Group by month from a particular date python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of account statement that contains date, debit and credit.
Lets just say salary gets deposited every 20th of the month.

I want to groupby date column from every 20th of each month to find sum of debits and credits. For e.g., 20th Jan to 20th Feb and so on.

```
date_parsed Debit   Credit
0   2020-05-02  775.0   0.0
1   2020-04-30  209.0   0.0
2   2020-04-24  5000.0  0.0
3   2020-04-24  25000.0 0.0
... ... ... ...
79  2020-04-20  750.0   0.0
80  2020-04-15  5000.0  0.0
81  2020-04-13  0.0 2283.0
82  2020-04-09  0.0 6468.0
83  2020-04-03  0.0 1000.0
```

I am not sure but pd.offsett can be used with groupby.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra month column which truncates up or down based on the day of month. Then its just `groupby` and `sum`. E.g. month 2020-06 would include dates between 2020-05-20 and 2020-06-19.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_parsed': ['2020-05-02', '2020-05-03', '2020-05-20', '2020-05-22'], 'Credit': [1,2,3,4], 'Debit': [5,6,7,8]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_parsed)
df['month'] = np.where(df.date.dt.day < 20, df.date.dt.to_period('M'), (df.date + pd.DateOffset(months=1)).dt.to_period('M'))
print(df[['month', 'Credit', 'Debit']].groupby('month').sum().reset_index())
```

Input:

```
  date_parsed  Credit  Debit
0  2020-05-02       1      5
1  2020-05-03       2      6
2  2020-05-20       3      7
3  2020-05-22       4      8
```

Result:

```
     month  Credit  Debit
0  2020-05       3     11
1  2020-06       7     15
```